# Chrome extension local storage not persisting

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Within my chrome extension i have a popup options page where i can add URL's. Im finding when navigating between pages, the URL's are stored fine. As soon as i go from a HTTPS page to a HTTP page, the URLs in local storage are deleted. Does anybody know why this could be?

Just as a note, im using

```
localStorage["URL_LIST"] = theUrl;
```

rather than

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue};
```

Could this be part of the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is your storage operation done in a popup, or in a content script? Each origin has its own separate `localStorage` store. The origin of the popup should not change as you navigate, but the origin of a content script will match the origin of the target page. (Origin is scheme + host + port, so changing from an HTTP scheme to an HTTPS scheme changes the origin, just as changing to a different host would.)

Comment: My local storage operation is actually on an options page for my extension, so this shouldnt be the issue? Also if i set the localStorage value on a HTTP website, then go to a HTTPS site, then return to a HTTP site, i see no entry in the localStorage, meaning its somehow been wiped?

Comment: Just to let you guys know, i was using localStorage.clear(key) rather than localStorage.removeItem(key) to remove the individual entry. Im guessing .clear(key) was actually clearing the entire local storage.

Comment: @DomShahbazi - You should write up an answer to this question so it appears as answered and also helps future visitors with the same problem. When you self-answer, just write your answer as if this were a stranger's post and you were providing a nice answer. Good luck and thanks for participating!